# Ideas on interfacing two separate systems. One is a windows application while the other is a Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, interface, desktop-application

I'm looking for ways for two separate systems to talk seamlessly. As mentioned above, one is a .NET web application on Oracle DB and another is a .NET Windows application on a MSSQL DB. Since this interaction has to be between a desktop app and web app, we had to come up with the idea of creating webservices for both the systems.

- Service A, would expose methods to add/update/get data from the MSSQL
  DB used by the Desktop App.
- The Service B would expose methods to add/update/get data from Oracle
  DB used by the Web App.

The Web App consumes service A. Desktop App consumes Service B. Now my question is what is a good way for the two systems to remain in sync.  For example, in the event of a failure of communication between Service A and Web app, what would be the failsafe way to ensure data integrity on both systems?

A schedule windows service that runs on a daily basis was suggested. but how about doing it on demand? We are talking a bout updating atleast a 20- 25 tables to begin with on both sides.

Comment: How often does the data change?  Does it change in both systems or just one of them?  DB triggers might work for relatively low volume transactions but you can overwhelm the database with locks if you're firing off too many identical triggers.  You might want to send updates to a third middle database and have both of these systems refresh themselves from there.  Lots of answers but all depends on the nature of these systems.

Comment: I'm very close to voting to close this, either as too vague or as not constructive. Please give more detail about the interaction between these applications. In particular, both the web and desktop applications are driven by users; will the same users be using both? What sort of sync do you need?

Comment: Both the apps are driven by users. The web app would be driven by one set of users, like appointment-schedulers, doctors , nurses etc. The other App would be driven by say billing users.  A typical scenario would be this- an Procedure/exam is scheduled, performed, completed and finally signed off by a Doctor in the Web app. The Data after that point has to reach the desktop App for billing users who bill and submit claims from the desktop app. Every time any correction /chnage has been made after that point in the Web app, should be replected in the Desktop app, for correct billing.

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way would be to create triggers in the databases which invokes an external sync application.

[Database trigger that communicates with an external program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319987/database-trigger-that-communicates-with-an-external-program)

Comment: DB Triggers has been tried and tested. and is being reserved as a backup mechanism if the webservices cannot provide adequate syncing. Thanks for the input.